# Exporting/Importing ArrayList with objects to my application with file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I am building an application which contains an array and 2 ArrayLists with objects.
One ArrayList for Customers, one for Orders and the Array is for the default items of the shop.

Now I am in the GUI implementation and I am trying to add this functionality:

I want to export to a file the 2 object ArrayLists I got.
I have succesfully exported the ArrayLists like this(the chooser just selects the folder):

```
FileOutputStream fos;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
fos = new FileOutputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"/orders");
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(save);
oos.close();
```

Now, I close the application.
 I want to import the saved ArrayLists to my app, but even when it says it is successful, my methods for running through the ArrayLists don't work(for example a method that just displays the contents of them).

I use this code to import them:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"/orders");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
ArrayList<CafeOrders> itemOrders = (ArrayList<CafeOrders>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Of course there are try-catch etc in the code, I am just posting the import/export methods.

There are separate buttons for each and they both seem to work(I get my file which contains data as well).

I am implementing my classes with Serialization.

Comment: Try printing the list size after deserialisation. Your code looks fine. If there is no exception, you should definitely have your objects back.

Comment: I can't..don't know what's the problem. I have this code in CafeManagerUI.class. I have CafeManager.class that initializes the ArrayLists and has other code. And 3 more constructor classes for the arrays. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just add print statements to see what happens...